# Present continuous or "going to"

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, semi-modals

Imagine this scenario:

I reserved in a restaurant two days ago. Today I've met my friend and have told him:

> 1. "I **am dining** out in a restaurant next Monday."

Here is my question: is present continous better than "going to" in that case? I chose present continuous because I have already reserved. Am I true? Or would it be better to say:

> 2. "I **am going to dine** out in a restaurant next Monday."

Comment: I haven't seen the case in English (yet), but there are other  languages in which you can use the "whole" present tense, preferably continuous, for reporting future definite actions.

Comment: Either is acceptable; there is no consistent difference in meaning.

Comment: Please edit your question and get rid of the ALL CAPS in the title

Comment: @MARamezani "Tomorrow I'm finally leaving the country", etc.

Comment: "I reserved in" would be more natural as "I made a reservation at". Also you need to capitalize "Monday".

Comment: Yes, your reason for choosing #1 over #2 for the context that you gave is reasonable, imo. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to dine out at/in a restaurant next Monday.

I am dining at/in a restaurant next Monday.

In this context, you can use either "the present continuous" or "be going to", without any difference in meaning. Even you can use "will" in this sentence, as mentioned by J.R. in his reply.

However, if you want your sentence to be more precise, you can use 
the first sentence, which expresses the action that is more likely to happen because of the arrangements you have made.

According to grammar, the present continuous is indicative of intention/decision + arrangements, whereas the use of "be going to" merely expresses your intention/decision.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you've already made a reservation doesn't change the tense. Since you're not dining out until next Monday, you should use a future tense. Use either:

> I will dine at a restaurant next Monday.

or:

> I'm going to dine at a restaurant next Monday.

I made a couple changes to your suggested wording:

- I like the preposition *at* instead of *in*; *in* is not wrong, but I prefer *at*.
- I changed *dine out* to *dine*. I might use *eat out*, but I prefer *dine* over *dine out* in this sentence.

I don't consider those corrections – more like suggested improvements. Local dialects may vary.